# What is wrong with my code C (read in file) -wc Unix command program

Tags: c, file-io, c-strings

Basically I'm supposed to make a program that copies the Unix -wc command. Flags -l, -w, -c, and -L are supposed to display # of lines, # of words, # of characters, and # of characters in line, respectively.

I am having trouble reading in a text file (first time doing it in C). I used GDB and discovered my problem lies in reading in the file. After awhile it just reads in null characters for whatever reason.

Please assume everything is right with my code except for reading in the file.

Here is my code:

```
void readInFile(char** argv, int arg, int addFlags, int argc)
{
   FILE *myFile;
   char c;
   int wordCount = 0, lineCount = 1, longestLine, characterAmount = 0;
   int charactersInLine = 0;

   myFile = fopen(argv[arg], "r");
   if(!myFile)
   {
      printf("%s not found!", argv[arg]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   while(c != EOF)
   {
      c = fgetc(myFile);
      putchar(c);
      characterAmount++;
      charactersInLine++;

      if(c == ' ')
         wordCount++;
      if(c == '\n')
      {
      if(charactersInLine > longestLine)
         longestLine = charactersInLine;
      charactersInLine = 0;
      lineCount++;
      wordCount++;
   }
}
```

Thanks for you time!

Comment: As a general tip, you should probably compare `c` to `'\n'` and `' '`, rather than their numeric values. It makes things much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is becoming one of the  most common problems, heh.

You're missing that `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`. This is because `EOF` is not a valid character, so a larger type is needed. See [this documentation, for instance](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc).

You're also testing `c` *before* assigning it for the first time, which basically makes your code rely on whatever happens to be in the uninitialized variable. This is a problem.

Also, you should probably test for `EOF` *before* counting.

Further, it's considered a bad idea to use magic numbers in code.

This:

```
if(c == 32)
```

can be written:

```
if(c == ' ')
```

and this:

```
if(c == 10)
```

can be:

```
if(c == '\n')
```

which are both clearer, in my opinion.

Comment: Ok I changed my code as suggested in my program and on here but I'm still not understanding what I should replace fgetc with. Thanks a lot. Still new to C programming.

Comment: Don't forget to initialize c, or use a different loop